# Maximum resistance on P-MOSFET gate pull-up

Tags: batteries, pullup, pmos

I have a P-MOSFET between my lithium battery and load. The P-MOSFET will only conduct if the battery's voltage is above a certain threshold to prevent over-discharging. The circuit is as shown below:

[image: circuit1]

The IC monitoring the battery voltage is as below. When voltage measured by the voltage divider R131/R132 crosses the 800 mV threshold the "Reset1" is connected to ground, but is otherwise an open drain.

[image: circuit2]

I believe a 10 kΩ resistor on R116 is a poor choice; it will drain my battery very quickly. I was planning to experiment with higher resistor values, but how can I do so systematically?  Meaning, what will tell me what the greatest resistance on R116 is that I can use and still prevent the P-MOSFET from conducting?

[Voltage monitor](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps37-q1.pdf?ts=1651202333363&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS37-Q1%253FkeyMatch%253DTPS37AB7806FDSKRQ1%2526tisearch%253Dsearch-everything%2526usecase%253DOPN)

[P-MOSFET](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FQT3P20-D.PDF)

Comment: You should supply a link to the datasheet for the battery monitor: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps37-q1.pdf?ts=1663597585697&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS37-Q1

Comment: What's the maximum possible battery voltage?

Comment: It is a 2 cell Li Ion battery so I’d say 8.4V

Comment: The main limit on the upper value of R116 is possible leakage from other sources. In this case 1 or even 10 megohm should work if there are no extraneous currents.

Comment: I think the MOSFET is the wrong way around.  You need to consider the body diode.

Comment: Please refrain from using a block with three pins to represent a MOSFET. Is this done in KiCAD? If yes, there are pre-defined MOSFET symbols you can use.